# Print without newline under function doesn't work as it should

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a progress bar in the terminal, by repeatedly printing `#` symbols on the same line.

When i tell Python to not add newlines - using `print('#', end='')` in Python 3 or `print '#',` in Python 2 - it prints as desired, but not until the whole function is finished. For example:

```
import time

i = 0

def status():
    print('#', end='')

while i < 60:
    status()
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
```

This should print '#' every second but it doesn't. It prints them all after 60 seconds. Using just print('#') prints it out every second as expected. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you try to reinvent wheels? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fish/

Comment: I use a solution based on [this](http://nadiana.com/animated-terminal-progress-bar-in-python) which is very cool, imo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is buffering the output until a newline (or until a certain size), meaning it won't print anything until the buffer gets a newline character `\n`. This is because printing is really costly in terms of performance, so it's better to fill a small buffer and only print once in a while instead.

If you want it to print immediately, you need to flush it manually. This can be done by setting the `flush` keyword argument to `True`.

```
import time

word = "One letter at a time"

for letter in word:
    print(letter, end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably need to flush the output buffer after each `print` invocation. See [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `strip()` function.

Comment: This does not address the problem.